# why is this Spring AOP pointcut not triggered?

Tags: java, spring, aop

I'm writing very basic schema-based Spring AOP, here's the .xml

```xml
<bean id="aoplistener" class="tao.zhang.Listener"/>

<aop:config>
  <aop:aspect ref="aoplistener">                
    <aop:pointcut id="whenCalled" expression="execution(* callme(..))" />
    <aop:after method="scream" pointcut-ref="whenCalled" /> 
  </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

The method **scream()** in tao.zhang.Listener just prints out some text, **and is supposed to be executed whenever a method callme() is called.**

I have a bean called **logger** which has the methods log() and callme()

```java
public void log(){
    callme();
    System.out.println("Hello from logger ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
}

public void callme(){
    System.out.println("I'm called");
}
```

Note that callme() is called by log()

Now I have a scheduler which calls log() every 5 seconds:

```xml
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="logger" method="log" fixed-rate="5000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Strangely, **scream()** is not invoked, but if callme() is called directly:

```xml
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="logger" method="callme" fixed-rate="5000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

**scream()** is invoked!

Any suggestions? It seems to me that this pointcut doesn't match methods called inside another method ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring AOP only traps a method call when the call is done through a bean handle (because the interceptor is applied through the use of a proxy object) and not when the method is called directly.

To make your code work, you need to either switch to using AspectJ (which works by rewriting the class's bytecode, which allows it to intercept far more things and to do so more transparently) or to change how you call `callme()` so that it is via a bean handle:

```
SomeClass selfRef;

public void log(){
    selfRef.callme();
    System.out.println("Hello from logger ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
}

public void callme(){
    System.out.println("I'm called");
}
```

You need to configure the `selfRef` field explicitly; it *won't* be autowired.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks a lot! I was just chewing this sentence from the spring manual book : `Spring AOP only supports method execution join points for Spring beans`

Comment: I found that it helped me a lot to know how Spring worked. If it does anything fancy (including AOP) it gives you a proxy object that contains the interception points it requires. That proxy object — the bean handle, if you will — is how you are supposed to do _all_ calls on the bean, and you shouldn't go behind Spring's back by calling via `this` (which is what a raw `callme()` does; the `this.` is implicit).

Comment: I now feel that Spring AOP is hardly useful in many cases. In my current project, I want to take some log whenever `callme()` is called, and `callme()` is used by various methods in this class as a sub-routine, which is a very common situation.

Comment: @Tao: Well, your choices are to refactor into two (or more) beans, call by the self-handle trick, or to use AspectJ to do the interception (as that can do what you want). In _my_ code, I mostly dealt with things by refactoring and I also had some use of the self-trick, but I avoided AspectJ as I already had other bytecode rewriting systems in place and didn't want to try to get the whole system to play nicely. (It was complex enough already!)