# Losing autowired attributes after executed the interceptor from Spring AOP

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-ioc, spring-aspects

After a lot of time waste trying to find a answer, I decided to post this doubt.
I have a class that I would like to intercept by the Spring AOP.

ObjectToBeProxied.java

```
package com.ee.beans; 

@Service
@Component
@Transactional
public ObjectToBeProxied implements IObjectToBeProxied {
    @Autowired
    private ParameterValueService parameterValueService;

    public void doStuff() {
        // do something before the call
        getSelfRef().findEventParameterValue(new ParameterValueFilter());
        // do something after
    }

    @HandleException
    private Boolean findEventParameterValue(ParameterValueFilter parameterValueFilter) {
        ParameterValue parameterValue = getSelfRef().parameterValueService.findParametertValueByFilter(parameterValueFilter);
        return parameterValue.value();
    }

    private ObjectToBeProxied getSelfRef() {
        return (ObjectToBeProxied) AopContext.currentProxy();
    }
}
```

ExceptionHandlerAspect.java

```
package com.ee.aspects;    

@Component
public class ExceptionHandlerAspect {

    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ObjectToBeProxied.class);

    public Object handleAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        // Handling the exception. Need to continue either the method throws a expcetion
        // but it need to be logged
        try {
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // something to handle the exception
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Spring AOP configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy expose-proxy="true" proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:spring-configured />

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ee.beans"/>

    <bean id="exceptionHandlerAspect" class="com.ee.aspects.ExceptionHandlerAspect" />

    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect id="exceptionHandlerConfig" ref="exceptionHandlerAspect">

            <!-- Trata exceções lançadas -->
            <aop:pointcut id="exceptionHandlerAroundMethod" expression="execution(* com.ee.beans.ObjectToBeProxied.*(..)) &amp;&amp; @annotation(com.ee.exceptions.HandleException)" />
            <aop:around pointcut-ref="exceptionHandlerAroundMethod" method="handleAround" />
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
```

When I call the method `ObjectToBeProxied.doStuff()`, `ObjectToBeProxied.parameterValueService` autowired is ok, not null.
But, when the aspect intercept the method call `ObjectToBeProxied.findEventParameterValue(..)` and execute the `ExceptionHandlerAspect.handleAround(..)`, the `ObjectToBeProxied.parameterValueService` is not ok, it's null.
Debugging it, I can figure out that the Spring Aspect return the `ObjectToBeProxied` proxy after intercept it, but without the autowired attributes objects.
Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: I do not think you need to use AopContext.currentProxy(). Do you have a good reason to do that? If not, remove getSelfRef() method and tell me what happens.

Comment: Get rid of expose-proxy="true" in your aspectj config as well

Comment: I'm following thoses advices http://stackoverflow.com/a/9223740/2765583 and http://www.intertech.com/Blog/secrets-of-the-spring-aop-proxy/. But following your advice, the aspect doesn't work normally, the `ExceptionHandlerAspect.handleAround(..)` was not triggered.

Comment: I can note that, note only the autowired fields are losing reference, but all the other fields, like as the `AopContext.currentProxy()` reset the object or return a close of it.